# How to redirect to the correct domain with Apache?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have an application available on my server's 8080 port. I want to redirect all users to myserverhostname:8080 if they access to the application using the IP address (http://0.0.0.0:8080) or using any other domain name pointing to the server.

I want to do the redirection with .htaccess without adding any vhost. The current vhost already serving correctly with any hostname at the port 8080.

My current .htaccess give me redirection loop.

Here is it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^server1.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://server1.example.com:8080/$1 [L,R]
```

I think that the RewriteCond doesn't see any difference, the redirection should be disabled when `%{HTTP_HOST}` is already `server1.example.com`.

Answer (score 0):

Default web HTTP port is 80, so check this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://server1.example.com:8080/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: My goal is:
https://www.mywebsite.com : no redirection
https://www.mywebsite.com:8080 : redirected to https://server1.example.com:8080